# How to profile JQuery/JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid component for displaying ajax tree grid.
With some quantity of data (tree with 200 branches, 2-3 items in each) - the grid begins to freeze in FireFox. Then I get a window asking whether to stop the script or continue.

What is the prescription to debug and resolve this?
I can debug my code, but I am not sure how to debug js libraries and their nuances.

Is it more likely JQuery, JQGrid or FireFox problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Firebug or IE 8's profiler to trace down the problem.

Note that jqGrid got *significantly* faster if you enable the [gridview option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) in jqGrid 3.5+, though I don't think that works for trees. But start with the profiler.

Comment: Indeed, greedview doesn't work with tree, but it's goal is to reduce the number of $() calls per grid item. I guess I need to follow this path

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you are way over with this. Just linking for referencing purpose. Check out [Deep Profiling jQuery Apps](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-profiling-jquery-apps/). A brilliant `jQuery plugin` that all you need to know how `jQuery` is freezing you.